# Rails scope defined in a class_eval block or instance_eval block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a little confused by [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) example on ActiveSupport::Concern from the documentation:

```
module M
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.class_eval do
      scope :disabled, -> { where(disabled: true) }
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    ...
  end
end
```

`self.included` in a Module is called when you include or extend the Module in a Class. `base` refers to the object, whether it is a class object or object instance. `extend` on `base` will include the methods in Module as singleton methods on `base`. `include` will add the methods to the class object's instances.

However, class_eval also is used to add instance methods to a class object's instances. Yet, `scope` is a class method:

> Adds a class method for retrieving and querying objects.

Since `scope` is a class method, why is the example using `class_eval` rather than `instance_eval`?

Comment: When the class_eval block is called, it is calling the class method. This article helps: http://engineering.appfolio.com/appfolio-engineering/2013/06/17/ruby-mixins-activesupportconcern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class_eval` is more powerful than `instance_eval`.

With class eval, you can evaluate code in the *context* of the class, allowing you to define and call class methods, instance methods, and more:

```
Greeter = Class.new

Greeter.class_eval do
  def self.friendly?
    true
  end

  def say_hi
   "Howdy!"
  end
end

donato = Greeter.new
donato.say_hi # => "Howdy!"
Greeter.friendly? # => true
```

`instance_eval` instead evaluates code with the target instance as the receiver, so you'd have to be a bit more crafty if you're trying to define instance methods:

```
Greeter = Class.new

Greeter.instance_eval do
  def friendly?
    true
  end

  define_method(:say_hi) { "Howdy!" }
end

donato = Greeter.new
donato.say_hi # => "Howdy!"
```